# Resteasy: what does bytes have to do with producing and consuming "text/plain"?

Tags: resteasy

I'm not sure why the below produces and consumes "text/plain" since we're dealing with Bytes.

According to oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Bytes is 8 bits and "has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive)."  So what does that have to do with "text"?

```
@Path("/")
public class MyService 
{
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public byte[] get() 
    {
        return "hello world".getBytes();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("text/plain")
    public void post(byte[] bytes) 
    {
        System.out.println(new String(bytes));
    }
}
```

I can understand Post clearly produces text as it's String.

Please keep answers understandable.  Thanks again.

Comment: Where did you find this code? It does seem clearer to use `String` instead of `byte[]` here.

Comment: The book is RESTful Java with Jax-rs 2.0  The above code was to demonstrate one can use byte[] to send and receive everything, which I didn't understand at the time.

Comment: Still not too clear, though I can see Lefloh's explaination about the UTF-8 chart values.  Here's what the author wrote "byte[]
A raw array of bytes can be used for the input and output of any media type. Here’s an example [the above example]."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A String is a list of characters. Each character points to a value in a charset table. So if you look in the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) or [UTF-8](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec) table you can see that the decimal value 65 points to the capital 'A'.

With this information you can convert from a byte to a String and back:

```
new String(new byte[] {65}) // A
"A".getBytes("UTF-8")[0] // 65
```

If you have a restful resource your JAX-RS runtime will choose the according [MessageBodyWriter](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) for the ContentType you have specified with `@Produces("text/plain")`. This MessageBodyWriter knows how to convert a byte[] to `text/plain`.

But as [@Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14955/thilo) already commented: Returning a String seems clearer (as long as you don't read e.g. a byte[] from a file and don't want to convert it to a String on your own).

Comment: @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public byte[] get() 
    {
        return "hello world".getBytes();
    }

Comment: here, @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public byte[] get() 
    {
        return "hello world".getBytes();
    }   note it returns a byte[]; are you saying that I can put String in place of byte[] here?  Also, are you saying that ""A".getBytes("UTF-8")[0] // 65" will output 65 to a readable text file?  I'm still not sure what the author was trying to say.  Why would anyone want to send by Bytes.  the author bill did say that it's more efficient (if I remember correctly).  Also, lastly, why use [0] in "A".getBytes("UTF-8")[0].  Thanks again.

Comment: sorry, I'm not allowed to edit my comments for x # of minutes per SOF.  Not sure why such restriction is in place.  also the return key would "save" and thus it won't allow me to immediately go back and edit.  And of course, there's no block mode for codes.

Comment: Sure, just try it! `public String get() { return "hello world"; }` should return the same result. Sending bytes may make sense if you already have bytes and don't want to convert them.